# How to evaluate integral with only a lower limit

Tags: integration, limits

Sorry it's been a while since I did this kind of thing, but I am wondering how to evaluate an integral where only the lower limit is given:

[image: Intergal in question]

Any help with this would be enormously appreciated.

EDIT - here is some more information from the textbook for context - maybe it will help?

[image: More context]

Comment: This is not a lower limit. It denotes some $2D$ domain and the integral is double. Without context, we can't say more.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How do you know it's two-dimensional? Is it because it's called $A$?

Comment: @Arthur We don't know for sure but it is a likely interpretation, given that one would usually write an integral over a domain this way and that the variable of integration is called $dA$ where $A$ doesn't occur in the function to be integrated and 'area' starts with an a.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks, I have added some more context - hopefully it means something

Comment: @quarague I agree that it's likely. But Yves sounded rather _certain_. I don't think that that's right. At least before we got more context.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I believe that without context, it could denote anything. I believe that area is by far the most likely, but nowhere near a necessity.

Comment: A is an area in this case, Ac refers to the area of the concrete cross section

Comment: @YvesDaoust No bad faith at all. It could be that $y$ is a function of a real variable named $A$ (for some unknown, but damn good reason), and that $A_c$ is some interval (or other measurable subset of the real line). That's not bad faith. That's just the uncertainty that follows as a direct consequence of lack of context. I am all for trying to understand what a poster means without having to hash out every single ambiguity. But I'm also for recognizing ambiguity when it's there. But it turns out in this case that it was area after all. Not that I had any _significant_ doubts.

Comment: @Arthur: the same way that $y$ does not denote the ordinate, a geometric quantity, but the room temperature.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answers are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This surface integral is a general formula where $A_c$ (the cross-section) is left unspecified. It is unsure if $E_{cm,0}$ denotes a constant or a function of $y$. You can't evaluate the integral as such.

In the case of a rectangular cross-section, integration on the width is trivial by symmetry (of the form $\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f(y)\,dy\,dx$) and is omitted, leading to a $1D$ integral.

Comment: Ecm,0 is a constant

Comment: OK, so re you saying that the general formula (with Ac) is not defined? That only the formula for a rectangular cross section is useful?

Comment: @Jaska: I never said that. I said that as long as $A_c$ is unspecified, there is nothing you can compute.

Comment: Well, assuming I do know Ac - this can be computed, then? Do I simply integrate the function with respect to A then substitute Ac in for A?

Comment: @Jaska: you should learn about multiple integrals, which are a bit more complicated than single ones. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I think this is a little over my head unfortunately. I need some help here with this since it's for work and I'm on something of a time limit, are you able to help me any further with this? I understand the case for the rectangular section with the upper and lower limits, that's no problem - I simply don't understand this 2d integral thing :-/

Comment: @Jaska: enter a new question with your particular $A_c$.